# source of a line return character in csv file exported with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I've been working on an app that uploads a csv file, does some math on it, then allows a user to download it.  Everything works great, but there's an annoying bug I'm trying to work out.

The file uploads to an html table and a new column of checkboxes are added to the end.  Don't be concerned with that now. (I'll probably have questions about this later.)  You can upload any csv file (just text with commas, no quotes) and then click the export csv file link.  The new file you have, when looked at in some text editors, has a line break character in it that doesn't belong. It happens on the second row on the final td.

here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k15ghb5d/) I made that demos the action.

it looks like this when I look at the code in the console:

```
<tr>
<td>Text1</td>
<td>text2</td>
<td>text3>
</td>
```

but all of the other tds are working fine.  Anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: `TypeError: cells is undefined` in your fiddle

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why that is.  When I test it out outside of JSF it is defined and works fine. Using the console to test in JSF doesn't work, or at least I'm not sure how to get to the working code.

Comment: Couldn't you provide an archive instead of a non working fiddle? I can't get your code work…

Comment: **Don't roll your own CSV parser.** This is a solved problem, use a library that has been tested and very likely works better than anything you come up with yourself. Maybe this one: https://github.com/gkindel/CSV-JS

Comment: http://packertest.com/Dropzone/striped.html is my working test file.

Comment: @Tomalak The CSV parser you are referring to requires me to have the file uploaded to a file. What I'm doing doesn't and that is more desirable for my application.

Comment: No, it absolutely does not require you to have an uploaded file. The readme shows you a *usage example*, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are in *desperate* need of an HTML templating solution (at the very least), I'll give you a nudge into the right direction.

The following depends on [gkindel/CSV-JS](https://github.com/gkindel/CSV-JS) for CSV parsing and [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for HTML creation:

```js
$(function () {
    var csvTemplateSrc = $('#csvTemplate').html(),
        csvTemplate = Handlebars.compile(csvTemplateSrc);

    $("#upload").click(function () {
        var filename = $("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase(),
            reader;

        if (typeof (FileReader) === "undefined") {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            return;
        }

        if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.:-]+\.(csv|txt)$/.test(filename)) {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
            return;
        }
        
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var rows;
            try {
                rows = CSV.parse(e.target.result);
            } catch (ex) {
                alert("Your CSV is has errors.\n\n" + ex.message);
                return;
            }
            $("#dvCSV").html(csvTemplate(rows));
        };
        reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
    });
    
    $(".export").click(function (event) {
        exportTableToCSV($('#dvCSV>table'), 'export.csv');
        $('a.export').css({"background-color": "#ddd"});
    });
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('first', function(context, options) {
    return options.fn(context[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/gkindel/CSV-JS/master/csv.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/handlebarsjs/3.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
<a href="#" class="export">Export Data to CSV</a>
<div id="dvCSV"></div>

<script id="csvTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table width="100%" class="sortable">
    {{#first .}}
    <tr width="100%">
        {{#each .}}
        <td>
            <select id="Value_{{@index}}">
                <option value="None">N/A</option>
                <option value="name">Name</option>
                <option value="Lat">Lat</option>
                <option value="Lon">Long</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        {{/each}}
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    {{/first}}
    {{#each .}}
    <tr>
        {{#each .}}
        <td>{{.}}</td>
        {{/each}}
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
</script>
```

**Notes**

- I think you can drop the filename check. If the CSV parser succeeds in parsing the file content that's proof enough that the file is OK.
- Note the use of `{{@index}}` to create uniqe HTML IDs. Your code created duplicate IDs, which defies the point of having IDs in the first place (and it's not allowed in HTML)
- You should think about switching to an MVVM framework for the whole application. Frameworks like [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) handle all HTML templating and DOM manipulation (you could drop Handlebars and almost all of your jQuery) and you would not need any "convert HTML to CSV" functionality anymore, either. Give it a look.

Comment: Thanks for the learning experience.  Learned several things and this example will help make better code the next time around.